# UIView transform with 3D Sphere effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, 3d

I'm using google map SDK to display a map, and i would add a 3D effect on the UIView, to look like a sphere

**1/ First, i initialized the map**

```
mapView2 = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,100,100) camera:camera];
mapView2.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal;
mapView2.delegate = self;
[self addSubview:mapView2];
```

[image]

**2/ Then, i added a corner radius**

```
mapView2.layer.cornerRadius = mapView2.frame.size.width/2;
```

[image]

**3/ Finally i would add a 3D effect, to make the map as a sphere.**

[image]

How can I do the third part?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SCNSphere](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnsphere?language=objc) like this...

```
SCNSphere *sphere = [SCNSphere sphereWithRadius:50];
sphere.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = image;
```

...where image has been captured from your view thusly...

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mapView2.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
[mapView2.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add such a 3d effect to google map !!